# Consolidate filter and measure?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there a better way of trying to filter a table and apply a average to the filtered results?

Currently research online articles has brought me to creating a virtual table (CALCULATETABLE) and then a separate measure to AVERAGE the column value I require.

Filtered Table below

```
filtered_table = CALCULATETABLE ('ReportRawFigures',
ReportRawFigures[days_since_completed] < 29,
ReportRawFigures[3rd_party] = "Bloggs",
ISBLANK(ReportRawFigures[time_to_complete]) = FALSE(),
ISBLANK(ReportRawFigures[last_confirmed_issue]) = FALSE(),
ReportRawFigures[issue_status] = "")
```

Then a simple measure added:

```
average = AVERAGE(filtered_table[column])
```

Comment: What about `AVERAGEX`?

Comment: Why to you need to materialize such a table? Why not apply those filters to your Visual?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very bright... I figured it out.
You create the filtered table, then when you build you visual you simply select the column and chose to average its output..

Hope this helps anyone looking like I first did.